# Spacy NLP example: cant covert token into lowercase, throwing error

Tags: spacy, spacy-3

```
from collections import defaultdict
item_ratings = defaultdict(list)

for idx, review in data.iterrows():

    doc = nlp(review.text)

    matches = matcher(doc)
    
    found_items = set(doc[match[1]:match[2]].lower_ for match in matches)

    
for item in found_items:
        
    item_ratings[item].append(review.stars)
```

**Error:**

```
AttributeError: 'spacy.tokens.span.Span' object has no attribute 'lower_'
```

I need the tokens to be in lowercase, how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
found_items = set(doc[match[1]:match[2]].text.lower() for match in matches)
```

Like the error says, `Span` objects don't have `lower_`. You can use `text` and then that' just a string so you can lowercase it.